# Start program and dock with an existing program Delphi 2010

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

Is there a way in Delphi 2010 to start an application using ShellExecute then dock that application inside another?

I.e. Program A written in Delphi contains 1 form.  When the form is shown, Program B, written in C# is started up and docked client into Program A's form?

Paul

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can do this. You need to get hold of the window handle of the main form in the other process (call [`EnumWindows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633497.aspx)). Then call [`SetParent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633541%28VS.85%29.aspx) to make that window a child of your window.

You'll likely want to modify window style, position etc. Also call [`WaitForInputIdle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687022%28VS.85%29.aspx) before trying to find a window handle in the new process. You've got to give the new process a chance to get started.

What you now have is a pretty queer beast. Inside one container you have two processes. Each process has its own UI thread. You can show and interact with two modal dialogs at once. There's really no end to the fun you can have with this!

---

**EDIT**

Just for a bit of fun I had a go at writing a simple Delphi app to do this. It's rather brittle and only seems to work for very basic apps.  I think you could spend a long time trying to make this work well and still end up with an unsatisfactory result.  If I were you I'd look for other solutions, especially as you have the source for this C# app. Surely you could expose its functionality as an ActiveX?

Anyway, for your amusement I offer the following exceedingly un-polished piece of code:

```
program AppHost;

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Forms, Controls, ComCtrls;

{$R *.res}

procedure ResizePage(Page: TTabSheet);
var
  hwnd: Windows.HWND;
  Rect: TRect;
begin
  hwnd := Page.Tag;
  Rect := Page.ClientRect;
  MoveWindow(hwnd, Rect.Left, Rect.Top, Rect.Right-Rect.Left, Rect.Bottom-Rect.Top, True);
end;

type
  PEnumData = ^TEnumData;
  TEnumData = record
    ProcessID: DWORD;
    hwnd: HWND;
  end;

function EnumWindowsProc(hwnd: HWND; lParam: LPARAM): BOOL; stdcall;
var
  ProcessId: DWORD;
  EnumData: PEnumData;
begin
  EnumData := PEnumData(lParam);
  GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, ProcessId);
  if EnumData.ProcessID=ProcessID then begin
    EnumData.hwnd := hwnd;
    Result := False;
    exit;
  end;
  Result := True;
end;

procedure Absorb(PageControl: TPageControl; const App: string; StartupInfo: TStartupInfo);
var
  Page: TTabSheet;
  ProcessInformation: TProcessInformation;
  EnumData: TEnumData;
begin
  Page := TTabSheet.Create(PageControl);
  Page.PageControl := PageControl;
  Page.Caption := ChangeFileExt(ExtractFileName(App), '');
  CreateProcess(PChar(App), nil, nil, nil, False, 0, nil, nil, StartupInfo, ProcessInformation);
  WaitForInputIdle(ProcessInformation.hProcess, INFINITE);
  EnumData.ProcessID := ProcessInformation.dwProcessId;
  EnumData.hwnd := 0;
  EnumWindows(@EnumWindowsProc, LPARAM(@EnumData));
  Page.Tag := Integer(EnumData.hwnd);
  SetParent(HWND(Page.Tag), Page.Handle);
  ResizePage(Page);
end;

type
  TEventProvider = class
  private
    FForm: TForm;
    FPageControl: TPageControl;
    procedure FormResize(Sender: TObject);
  public
    constructor Create(Form: TForm; PageControl: TPageControl);
  end;

{ TEventProvider }

constructor TEventProvider.Create(Form: TForm; PageControl: TPageControl);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FForm := Form;
  FPageControl := PageControl;
  FForm.OnResize := FormResize;
end;

procedure TEventProvider.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to FPageControl.PageCount-1 do begin
    ResizePage(FPageControl.Pages[i]);
  end;
end;

procedure Main(Form: TForm);
var
  StartupInfo: TStartupInfo;
  PageControl: TPageControl;
begin
  Form.ClientHeight := 600;
  Form.ClientWidth := 800;
  Form.Caption := 'All your processes are belong to us';
  PageControl := TPageControl.Create(Form);
  PageControl.Parent := Form;
  PageControl.Align := alClient;
  StartupInfo.cb := SizeOf(StartupInfo);
  GetStartupInfo(StartupInfo);
  Absorb(PageControl, 'C:\Windows\Notepad.exe', StartupInfo);
  Absorb(PageControl, 'C:\Program Files\CommandLine\depends.exe', StartupInfo);
  TEventProvider.Create(Form, PageControl);
end;

var
  Form: TForm;

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm, Form);
  Main(Form);
  Application.Run;
  Form.Free;
end.
```

Comment: `EnumWindows` is the usual way. In your enumerate proc call `GetWindowThreadProcessId` and match it up against your new process's process ID.

Comment: I am assuming that shellexecute will give me the processid?

Comment: It returns a process handle, from which you can obtain the process ID ([`GetProcessId`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683215%28VS.85%29.aspx)). Make sure you know the difference between a process handle and a process ID.

Comment: ok thanks am going to look at this today.  When I get all of this working does that mean the c# program will not appear in the task bar or alt tab?  I want to make the user think they are using 1 program not 2

Comment: @Paul you'll likely have to modify the C# program's window styles anyway, and one of the things you can do is to remove it from the taskbar. Do you have source to the C# program?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your code sample David, have only just seen this so will try in the office tomm

Comment: The idea is that the program that I dock into my main application could be written in a variety of languages, e.g. c#, Silverlight, etc, which would make the ActiveX route more complex

Comment: @Paul I think you'll have great trouble getting an out-of-process solution to work, but I could be wrong! Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Yes I have access to the C# program

I need a solution that works irrespective of the language, but any program that is loaded in this way will be one that we write

GetProcessID returns 0?

All I have done for now is to produce 2 programs in Delphi, 1 calls the other

I then want to get dockapp2 to dock inside of dockapp1 and for the user to have no idea that this is a seperate program.

Having GetProcessID returning 0 is not ideal!

```
procedure TForm2.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var 
n: Integer;
n2: Integer;
begin
  n := ShellExecute(0, 'open', PChar('c:\temp\dockapp2\dockapp2.exe'), nil, nil,     SW_SHOWNORMAL); 
  n2:= GetProcessId(n);
 Caption := IntToStr(n2);
end;
```

Comment: `ShellExecute` does not a process handle. You code is invalid. You'd need `ShellExecuteEx`, and then the process handle would be returned in the struct that you pass to that function. Anyway, for this I'd use [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28VS.85%29.aspx) instead.

Comment: @Paul I can see that you are new to Stack Overflow, but it is wrong to add an answer that doesn't answer the question. This should have been either comments to my answer, an edit to the question, or even a new question.

Comment: @Paul Since you say that you have access to the source of the C# program, you might find it easiest to arrange that it runs in a borderless, non-resizable mode, no sysmenu etc. That way the user won't be able to do weird things to it once it is housed in your Delphi host.

Comment: Thanks David, I didnt see an add comment button when I went to respond to your other comment earlier sorry

Comment: ok we can do that thanks, its just a case of making it transparent

Comment: as in user not knowing its 2 programs